# How do I get Excel to pull data from multiple workbooks from exact dates based on an entered date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am running windows-7 and using Excel 2007 Enterprise.

I am a truck driver and need to catalog my pay based on a changing day to day system. I am paid per mile, per stop, per hour, or per flat rate depending on the type of route.

I have made a workbook that uses `=IF()` formulas to determine what pay scale to use and calculates how much I am to be payed automatically. As a result each workbook has 4 sheets, 1 sheet per trip as any more than 4 is so rare it may only happen once per year.

Sheet 1 pulls data from sheets 2, 3, and 4 automatically and fills in the correct cells and then recalculates my pay depending on what data is entered.

Now that I have a workbook for each day, as I can't combine days for several reasons not worth explaining here, I must have a total for each week to compare my gross earnings to. I have another workbook just for this reason, however I can't seem to get my weekly pay to pull data from my daily pay sheets as they are separate workbooks. I need my weekly pay to pull all total pay cells and total them on one sheet.

The cell in the daily pay is "B23 on Sheet-1", this is the location on all workbooks. I know this is a lot of information by I hope that it helps you understand what I need. So for what I need: I want to input the date that I am to be paid and have the workbook find the days needed to reference based on that date ie: 11/15/13 is pay for dates 11/03/13 - 11/08/13". now that it has the dates, find value in cell B23 on sheet-1  of all 7 dates and show it in this workbook. I can then have it compare my gross pay to what I should be paid if it is different, this part I already know how to do and already have it set up. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You're most likely going to need VBA, so in order to help you, we will need your naming convention for each workbook (day). This is because excel cannot reference closed workbooks via function and will need to open the books and pull the data (hard-coded) instead of referencing it. A good start would be [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801598/how-do-i-reference-to-another-open-or-closed-workbook-and-pull-values-back-i)

Comment: Each day is saved as the date ie: m-dd-yy. Each sheet is named Trip-1, Trip-2, ect. It should also be noted that I am a truck driver and not a code programer, some code may have to be dumb-ed down for me, I have a small understanding of code but no where near excel level. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So for your example, you need `[11-03-13.xls]Trip-1!B23` through `[11-08-13.xls]Trip-1!B23` right? Or is it on like summary!B23 rather than a trip?

Comment: On Trip-1 the trip pay from the other 3 trips is shown on the right and added to the total in another cell. So I don't believe it would be a summery. I just realized I made a mistake identifying the totals cell, B23 is the total for each sheet on its sheet, on Trip-1 all Trips are totaled together in cell O6. So yes I would need to open those dates that match the date that would be entered. I wish I could show my workbook for better understanding.

Comment: Totaled in O6? On which sheet, for the whole day?

Comment: I renamed my sheets when I first made the workbook, so Sheet-1 = Trip-1, Sheet-2 = Trip-2, ect... On Trip-1 **"Cell O2"** ='Trip-2'!B23  **"Cell O3"** ='Trip-3'!B23   **"Cell O4"** ='Trip-4'!B23   **"Cell O6"** =B23+O2+O3+O4. So as you can see on my daily pay workbook the fist worksheet shows the total of all trips for that day in **Cell O6**. I thought this would make accessing a total simple, I could be wrong. I have posted a screen shot of my workbook [Here](http://s976.photobucket.com/user/Kane1793/media/ExcellWorkbookDailyPayTemplate_zpsd5676488.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this and make sure you replace the `path` with the path on your computer where you keep your files.

How it works: Place this in a module in a new workbook, put the payday in cell `A1` and run the macro called `Total`. The dates and pay amounts will show up in columns B and C with the sum in `C7`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Total()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call getdates
Call openWBgetData
Range("c7") = [sum(C1:C6)]
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub getdates()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
j = 7

For i = 1 To 6
    Cells(i, 2) = Cells(1, 1).Value - j
    j = j + 1
Next

End Sub

Private Sub openWBgetData()
Dim k As Integer
Dim lng As Long
Dim path As Long
Dim wbname As String
path = "C:\path\to\"

For k = 1 To 6
    wbname = Cells(k, 2).Value
    Application.Workbooks.Open (path & wbname & ".xlsx")
    lng = Workbooks(wbname).Sheets("Trip-1").Range("O6").Value
    Workbooks(wbname).Close
    Cells(k, 3) = lng
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what or where to put this, I'm not that advanced in coding. To use something like this I would need a step by step approach.

Comment: I have added my other workbook via screen shot [Here](http://s976.photobucket.com/user/Kane1793/media/WeeklyPaySheet_zps55c76b11.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0) The dates in column "I" are calculated based on the date placed in "B3". I need cell "B7" to display the total pay on "Trip-1" Cell "O6" of Workbook "11-03-13", and cell "B8" to display the total pay on "Trip-1" Cell "O6" of Workbook "11-04-13", and so on. Each month is in its own folder kept in each year folder inside my work folder ie: E:-Work-2013-Nov-11-03-13. Thank you for your patience and help with this, I know I'm a novice.

Comment: enable the developer tab, go into it and insert a new module

Comment: I can't seem to get that code to work, it may be my fault, as I said I'm not a code person. maybe I can be more specific. on the workbook "Weekly Pay" I have cell B3 blank, when I put a date (11-15-13) in "B3" cells "I4-I10" subtract 6 to 12 days (11/03/13 - 11/09/13) and displays dates in cells "I4-I10" for the previous week that I was paid for in cell "B3". I need **a** cell to see "I4" has a date(11/03/13), pull that "Daily Pay" workbook saved as "11-03-13" and display the "Total Pay" found in cell-O6 from workbook-"11-03-13". Once I have a cell that displaying info from the cell I need I

Comment: can make it work. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with a formula and not use VBA, I seem to have an understanding of simple cell formulas, its the VBA I don't understand, I have never used VBA or any code like it before. I can do simple HTML, but not much more then that. Please help.

Comment: No, there isn't. Formulas cannot pull from closed workbooks. If you want to open the workbooks and use an `indirect` you could try that.